# Elastic search aggregation key value

Tags: elasticsearch

PRODUCT 1

```
   "attributes_list" : {
        "src1" : [
          {
            "aname" : "Manufacturer Standard Lead Time",
            "avalue" : "16 Weeks"
          },
          {
            "aname" : "Color",
            "avalue" : "red"
          },
          {
            "aname" : "Detailed Description",
            "avalue" : "Pre-Biased Bipolar
          },
          {
            "aname" : "DC Current Gain (hFE) (Min) @ Ic, Vce",
            "avalue" : "100 @ 10mA, 5V"
          },
          {
            "aname" : "Transistor Type",
            "avalue" : "2 NPN - Pre-Biased (Dual)"
          },
          {
            "aname" : "Mounting Type",
            "avalue" : "Surface Mount"
          }

        ]
    }
```

PRODUCT 2-------------

```
   "attributes_list" : {
        "src1" : [
          {
            "aname" : "Lead Time",
            "avalue" : "16 Weeks"
          },
          {
            "aname" : "Color",
            "avalue" : "green"
          },
          {
            "aname" : "Description",
            "avalue" : "Pre-Biased Bipolar
          },
          {
            "aname" : "DC Current Gain (hFE) ",
            "avalue" : "100 @ 10mA, 5V"
          },
          {
            "aname" : "Transistor",
            "avalue" : "2 NPN - Pre-Biased (Dual)"
          },
          {
            "aname" : "Type",
            "avalue" : "Surface Mount"
          }

        ]
    }
```

The question is
How can i get all the colors (avalues) by key.
like:
aggs
Colors
Red
doc_count 10
Green
doc_count 5

Simple is
We need to get all the colors by key.

We have tried different aggs queries on avalue but all are getting all the avalues. We need just to get all the avalue:colors [red,green etc ] by aname:color.

Comment: Have you considered duplicating attributes in a separate field as an object? Then it would be as easy as a simple aggregation on `attributes_obj.src1.Color` or `attributes_obj.src1.Lead_Time`.

Comment: Sorry i did not get what do you mean for separated field.

Comment: The above example is exactly same data what we have in attributes.

Comment: So you can update document in your indexing pipeline to look like this: https://gist.github.com/ilvar/6631f34624cdc0dc199cdea8cca1946a - this will make aggregating the data you want very trivial.